# Where can I find examples of how to use the new Chinese words I learn,like a website?

Tags: characters, vocabulary

I'm kind of a beginner here and I often have problem remembering the vocabulary I learn and was thinking if someone could help and tell me where to find those words actually being used, besides if you Know a dictionary that has examples in it pls tell me,thanks :)

Comment: Is it ok if other people demonstrate the use of language?

Comment: Yes,that would be special,but I think it would be really time consuming coz there are so many words out there ! :)

Answer (score 1):

http://chinesepod.com/dictionary/english-chinese/

Just enter the character you're interested and it'll list several sentences containing the character, I can't guarantee the quality though, I rarely use this service.

https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php

This is my go-to dictionary, for many characters it'll show you the stroke order and for many words it'll even show you example usage, though to be honest I've noticed that the example usage doesn't always align with the definition given.

Comment: 小奥利奥,this is perfect, it's just what I've been looking for,thanks alot 

Answer (score 0):

Hacking Chinese has an article [*21 essential dictionaries and corpora for learning Chinese*](https://www.hackingchinese.com/21-essential-dictionaries-and-corpora-for-learning-chinese/) which lists multiple example-sentence websites.

I personally use:

- Pleco https://www.pleco.com/ (on my iPhone)
- Jukuu http://www.jukuu.com/
- YouDao http://youdao.com/
- Zhonghua Yuwen corpus http://corpus.zhonghuayuwen.org/CnCindex.aspx
- Baidu https://www.baidu.com/ (click on the 资讯 link for more formal sentences)

(Also see [my answer](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1653/8099) to [*What resources do you actively use to study Chinese, and why?*](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/what-resources-do-you-actively-use-to-study-chinese-and-why) on meta for other resources I actively use.)

Comment: Thanks dear Becky, I checked it out and it was really helpful, I'll never forget your help, thanks for taking your time:)